# How to change the java version in weblogic 10.3 (10gR3)?

Tags: java, netbeans, deployment, weblogic, java-6

I am using Weblogic 10gR3. I have webappliation built using netbeans and compiled on java 1.7.
When deployed on the server I get the error.

[image: Weblogic Deployment error]

I searched the net and found probable cause to be version mismatch. When checked I found java 1.6 installed on weblogic.[image: Weblogic version].

I tried changing it in \bea\wlserver_10.3\common\bin\commEnv but still not changed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update the ${DOMAIN_HOME}/bin/setDomain.sh to set the JVM that you need.
You should concider recompile your web app with the good jdk.

Comment: Got it working... 

In setDomainEnv.sh it is SUN_JAVA_HOME=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_79
In commEnv.sh it is JAVA_HOME="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_79"


The difference is I had put SUN_JAVA_HOME in quotations, after I removed them it worked fine. (not sure why its difference in interpretation )  . Marking this as answer because Domain.sh also need to be changed to JAVA_HOME new version.